# Why can't I call a non-const member function on an element in an std::set?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, iterator, member-functions, stdset

I hve the next code:

```
set<Item> temp_items;
set < Item >::iterator it;
temp_items = user->second.get_items();
for (it = temp_items.begin(); it != temp_items.end(); it++)
{
    if (counter == (choice - 1))
    {
        it->get_count();
    }
}
```

The item function i trying to call is:

```
int Item::get_count() { return _count; }
```

I don't have in here any const type that should prevent me from accessing the item object, and still, I get the next message:

> the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function
>
> object type is const

How can I fix it?

Comment: your function needs to be const.

Comment: @Hayt "_I dont have in here any const type that should prevent me from accessing the item object_" so you should probably explain why.

Comment: @Hayt Its worked! my teacher didnt teached me that. Why is that have to be const?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to replace a set in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077459/best-way-to-replace-a-set-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: you can only call const functions on set iterators.

**Explanation:**

The set is internally sorted by the `Item`. So when you access a reference (via iterator) you are not allowed to do something to change the value of the `Item` (this was actually easily possible in earlier c++ versions).

What happens when you accidentally change the value this would not change the internal "ordering" accordingly and the lookup can fail even while the object is "there" in theory.

Imagine this with numbers you have a set

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Now you change the value of 9 to 0 (by reference)

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0
```

Now when you would look for a 0 and the container has a smart lookup it would use a binary search and would assume 0 is on the far left. This would result in 0 not being found.

(**Note**: this is just a simplified example. Not a definite explanation on how a set is implemented)

That is why the reference to the key is a `const` reference and why you only can call const functions on those (same applies for keys on a map).

Comment: I have get a problem when I trying to do __const__ to a 'setter' because its trying to change variables in the object. Hoe can I do that if not like that?

Comment: @dfsfgsfg thats the point of everything. You should not change an object stored in a set after it has been inserted because it can cause the problem I just described.

Answer (score 1):

A `set` always gives you back objects that are `const`. In your loop, `*it` refers to a `const Item`. You're trying to call a member function, `get_count()`, that isn't `const` qualified - it is only allowed be called on non-`const` objects, hence the failure.

You can fix this by marking your function `const`:

```
int get_count() const { return _count; }
               ^^^^^^^
```

Note: you're calling a function that has no side-effects and not using its return type. This doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: What should I do when I use a 'setter' instead of a 'getter'? because then I have to change the variable./

Comment: @dfsfgsfg You can't use setters with things in a set.