# Best way to replace a set in C++

Tags: c++, set, std, deque

I have to refactor old code that looks like this (I am not a very proficient C++ coder)

```
 std::set<SomeObject>::iterator it = setobject.begin();

 do {
     it->setProperty1ToNextValue();
     it->getProperty2();
     it->getProperty3();
     it++ 
 } while (it != setobject.end());
```

Basically I want to iterate through the elements of the set and get and set/update some of their properties.
I cant use the original set since I run in the problems described in this thread
[the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function object type is const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791941/the-object-has-type-qualifiers-that-are-not-compatible-with-the-member-function)

I am thinking of replacing the set with a dequeue (it will involve some rewriting) since I will then be able to set and get properties on each element of the dequeue. Is this a good approach?

Comment: If the `std::set` policies don't apply anymore, what do you actually need? A `std::unordered_map` maybe? BTW, all of your function calls in the sample seem to be NOPs, unless there are any side effects. Consider posting _real code_.

Comment: Why do you think you can not use set?

Comment: You can't change the key properties of a set, but you can remove the item with the old properties and replace it with a new one. Having said that, if you are iterating through a set, you probably have the wrong data structure.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Do I have to specify a hash if I use std::unordered_map?

Comment: @JennyToy Yes, a hash is required for `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: @NeilButterworth You mean have two sets, looping through one and putting the changed object in a second set? (I assume I cant remove and replace while iterating over a set?)

Comment: @koalo Cant change individual properties of an object in the set.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I assume I could use std::unordered_set?

Comment: There is too few context here. You could even build a new set if you still need all the other advantages of set. Or use a fixed size array if you never add or remove anything...

Comment: It's impossible for us to make any suggestions because you haven't stated what you need. You didn't even say why you "can't use a set anymore". How you implement software is driven by ***requirements***.

Comment: `std::unordered_map` has a default hash, which is probably fine. I'm not sure @πάνταῥεῖ understood your question.

Comment: You should probably use a `while` rather than `do { ... } while`, since the condition will be true the first iteration if there are no elements in the set at the moment.

Comment: @NeilButterworth "...if you are iterating through a set, you probably have the wrong data structure." Really? Why? (`std::set` is required to be iterable...)

Comment: The modern way to iterate over all elements of a collection and do something with each of them, assuming that you don't need access to the actual iterator object (which seems to be the case here), is to use a foreach loop: `for (auto obj : setobject) { obj.setProperty1ToNextValue(); /* etc */ }`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie In addition to the fact that OP is not trying to find a value, it appears that the code is equivalent to a `std::transform` on the `set`. This is impossible without either knowing all the members of a set, or...iteration.

Comment: JennyToy, please [edit] your question to clarify what your needs are. In particular, it is still not clear why you think that you cannot use a `std::set`, or even why the old code must be changed at all. What are you hoping to accomplish? What restrictions do you have, and what problems are you facing?

Comment: @KyleStrand I went ahead and created a new set that has a copy of the modified objects in the original set. I was not able to change the objects in the original set since I get the same issue as described in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791941/the-object-has-type-qualifiers-that-are-not-compatible-with-the-member-function

Comment: "I am thinking of replacing the set with a dequeue (it will involve some rewriting) since I will then be able to set and get properties on each element of the dequeue. Is this a good approach?" It depends what requirements you have on that container. We do not have any knoweldge except you are iterating over it, how can we say if it is a good approach or not?

Comment: Ah, you're right! Sorry, I didn't think at all about how transforming the set would be an invalid operation. It seems the old code must have been buggy, then, since it appears to be modifying the elements without reorganizing the set to compensate? If you knew for certain that the modifications to the elements wouldn't change the key values (i.e. the pairwise element comparisons would remain the same after the transformation), then you could use a `const_cast`, though I wouldn't recommend that because you lose the compiler's safety guarantees.

Comment: There's an approach with a map structure that might work as well (because only the keys in a map must be immutable). Or, if only some elements will change, you could use a separate data structure to track which elements must change while you iterate, then remove those elements all at once, update them, and reinsert them.

Comment: Setting aside the ability to use range-`for` now: *Whyyyyyy* are you using `do`/`while` instead of `for`? (a) like everyone else does, (b) because that will not invoke undefined behaviour on an empty set like this does, and (c) because that will avoid the iterator polluting the surrounding scope. Also, you should cache the `end` iterator by declaring it along with the incremented one, so you don't call `end()` for every iteration, which is redundant however we slice it and possibly a hit to performance if the compiler doesn't optimise it out.

Comment: [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077459/best-way-to-replace-a-set-in-c#comment71446260_42077459), duplicate of [Why can't I call a non-const member function on an element in an std::set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791941/why-cant-i-call-a-non-const-member-function-on-an-element-in-an-stdset)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `std::set` works by keeping all the items in order according to the object's `<` operator.  The reason you cannot call non-const methods on your object is because there is risk that those methods will change the value returned by your objects `<` operator, and therefore effectively "reorder" the set under the hood without the `std::set` knowing.

While you haven't specified enough of what you are trying to do for us to provide the best answer, here is a couple ways to technically achieve calling some methods on your set. You can use `const_cast` to call methods you are sure won't modify the key.  Or you can put the items in a vector, call methods that might modify the "key", and then put them back in the original set.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

class SomeObject
{
    std::string key;
    int         data;

public:
    SomeObject( const std::string& key_, int data_ ) : key( key_ ), data( data_ )
    {}

    // For a item to be in a set, it must have a "<" operator that tells it how to order it
    bool operator <( const SomeObject& rhs ) const
    {
        return key < rhs.key;   
    }

    void setKey( const std::string& key_ )
    {
        key = key_;   
    }

    void setData( int data_ )
    {
        data = data_;   
    }
};

int main()
{   
     std::set< SomeObject > setobject;
     setobject.insert( SomeObject("c", 1 ) );
     setobject.insert( SomeObject("a", 1 ) );
     setobject.insert( SomeObject("b", 1 ) );

     // internally, the set will keep everything in order "a", "b", "c"

     // option 1 - use const_cast (risky!)
     {
         std::set< SomeObject >::iterator it = setobject.begin();

         do {
             // const_cast< SomeObject& >( *it ).setKey( "d" );  bad idea, now the set is jacked up because its not in the right order
             const_cast< SomeObject& >( *it ).setData( 2 );
             it++;
         } while (it != setobject.end());
     }

     // option 2 - put the items in the vector, call the methods, then put them back in the original set
     {
         std::vector< SomeObject > tempVec( std::begin( setobject ), std::end( setobject ) );
         std::vector< SomeObject >::iterator it = tempVec.begin();
         do {
             it->setKey( "d" ); 
             it->setData( 2 );
             it++;
         } while (it != tempVec.end());

         std::set< SomeObject > newSet( std::begin( tempVec ), std::end( tempVec ) );
         std::swap( newSet, setobject );  // put the new items back in the original setobject
     }



}
```